# Copying portions of Java swt images with alpha

Tags: java, swt

I’m using Java swt Images with full 32-bit color and alpha channels (org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image). I need to extract a rectangle of the image as a new image, including the full alpha channel information.

For example, I might have an Image sized 100×100, and I need to create a new Image with just the top-left 50×50 pixels exactly as they are in the 100×100 image. (I’m chopping, not rescaling.)

My original attempt was to create a blank image of the size I need (50×50 in this example), then get a GC for the new image, then draw the correct portion of the old image on the new image. The problem was that transparency wasn’t preserved. If my new image started opaque, then the result after a draw would be completely opaque. If my new image started transparent, then the result after a draw would be completely transparent (with all the RGB colors correct, but invisible because the alpha would be zero for all pixels).

My current solution is clunky: I use a GC to draw the image, then manually copy over the alpha channel row-by-row.

```java
/**
 * Returns a sub-rectangle from the image, preserving alpha transparency.
 * @param source The image from which to copy a portion
 * @param sourceData The ImageData of the source image
 * @param xInSource The x-coordinate in the source image from which to start copying
 * @param yInSource The y-coordinate in the source image from which to start copying
 * @param widthInSource The width (in pixels) of the copied image portion
 * @param heightInSource The height (in pixels) of the copied image portion
 * @param disp The display to use for the new image, or null for the current display
 * @return New image copied from a portion of the source.
 */
private static Image getRectHelper(final Image source, final ImageData sourceData,
        final int xInSource, final int yInSource, final int widthInSource, final int heightInSource, final Display disp)
{
    // In cases like extracting multiple frames at once, we need both the Image and its ImageData without
    // having to extract the ImageData over and over. That’s why this helper takes both parameters.

    // New up an image of the appropriate size
    final Display d = disp==null ? Display.getDefault() : disp;
    final Image dest = new Image(d, widthInSource, heightInSource);

    // This draws the colors from the original image, but does not set the destination alphas
    // (For the  Image class, alpha transparency doesn’t work well – it seems to have been tacked on as an afterthought.)
    final GC g = new GC(dest);
    g.drawImage(source, xInSource, yInSource, widthInSource, heightInSource, 0, 0, widthInSource, heightInSource);
    g.dispose();

    // Get a copy of the dest image data, then sets the destination alphas from the source image
    final ImageData destData = dest.getImageData();
    copyAlpha(sourceData, destData, xInSource, yInSource, widthInSource, heightInSource, 0, 0);

    // Construct a new image with the modified image data
    final Image ret = new Image(d, destData);
    dest.dispose();

    return ret;
}

/**
 * Copies a block of alpha channel information from the sourceData to the destaData. 
 * 
 * @param sourceData The source image data from which to copy alpha information
 * @param destData The destination image data to modify with new alpha information
 * @param xInSource The x-coordinate from which the alpha information should be copied
 * @param yInSource The y-coordinate from which the alpha information should be copied
 * @param width The width (in pixels) of the alpha information to copy
 * @param height The height (in pixels) of the alpha information to copy
 * @param xInDest The x-coordinate to which the alpha information should be copied 
 * @param yInDest The y-coordinate to which the alpha information should be copied
 */
private static void copyAlpha(final ImageData sourceData, final ImageData destData,
        final int xInSource, final int yInSource, final int width, final int height,
        final int xInDest, final int yInDest)
{
    final byte[] alphas = new byte[width];
    for (int ySrc = yInSource, yDst = yInDest; ySrc < yInSource+height; ++ySrc, ++yDst) {
        sourceData.getAlphas(xInSource, ySrc, width, alphas, 0);
        destData.setAlphas(xInDest, yDst, width, alphas, 0);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I’m new to Java, so I may be doing something wrong. Is the alpha channel really an afterthought for the swt Image class? Surely there’s a simpler and faster way to do this. I’m tempted to just use ImageData objects directly, and bypass GC use completely.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you might be missing is that there are multiple transparency types for an Image.  http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/ImageData.html#getTransparencyType()

In the resize code we use for SWT images, we first create a new Image and get its ImageData.  Then based on the transparency type of the original Image's ImageData, we do one of the following things:

- If SWT.TRANSPARENCY_ALPHA, then applying an alpha like in your example should do the trick.
- If SWT.TRANSPARENCY_PIXEL, then we set the ImageData's transparentPixel property to match the original image's ImageData.
- If SWT.TRANSPARENCY_MASK, then we set the maskData and maskPad properties of the new ImageData to match the original image's ImageData.

We then use the ImageData to create a new Image (dispose of the first) and draw on it using GC.

Hopefully the above can help you get closer to solving the issue.